# python dynamodb construct dynamic queries combined with boolean operations

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

The AWS examples of boto3's dynamodb are simplistic. I wanted to throw up a web form that allowed a user to pick any of the elements in a table and OR a number of options for any single field and AND all of the field filters together.

To do this I need to construct a series of conditions to OR together then AND all the resultant Or combinations, something like:
And([ Or([c1,c2,...]), Or([e1,e...]), Or([a1,a...]) ])

I do not know the number of terms for each Or, or the final And until runtime, so I need to be able to aggregate the filter terms together at runtime.

For all the queries below, here's my set of FilterExpressions:

```
c1 = Attr('class').eq(2)
c2 = Attr('class').eq(3)
c = Or([c1, c2])

e1 = Attr('exclusion').eq(0)

a1 = Attr('action').eq(2)
```

I'm able to do simple And/Or queries:

Combine 2 And conditions:

```
all = [a1, e1]
request = {'ConsistentRead': False, 'FilterExpression': And(*all)}
print ('dynamo scan params: {}'.format(request))
response = table.scan(**request)
print response['Count'], response['ScannedCount']
dynamo scan params: {'FilterExpression': <boto3.dynamodb.conditions.And object at 0x115d7d410>, 'ConsistentRead': False}
34 1166
```

Combine 2 Or conditions:

```
all = [c1,c2]
request = {'ConsistentRead': False, 'FilterExpression': Or(*all)}
print ('dynamo scan params: {}'.format(request))
response = table.scan(**request)
print response['Count'], response['ScannedCount']
dynamo scan params: {'FilterExpression': <boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Or object at 0x115d7dc90>, 'ConsistentRead': False}
51 1166
```

Combine multiple And and Or conditions:

I expect the syntax here is incorrect, but I'm unable to find any examples of this on the AWS or boto documentation.

```
all = [And([a1,e1]), Or([c1,c2])]
```

And that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but feels suboptimal:

```
            # 2 params are clazz and exclusion which are lists of matches
            # to be OR's together individually and ANDed at the end.
            # these map to the dynamo fields 'class' and 'exclusion'

            # Start with an empty aggregator filter:
            fe = None

            # I'm iterating over each "OR" item:
            # class is a list of enum values that should match in an OR condition
            if clazz:
                fe_class = None
                for x in clazz:
                    fe_x = Attr('class').eq(ArticleClass[x].value)
                    if not fe_class:
                        fe_class = fe_x
                    else:
                        fe_class = (fe_class | fe_x)

                # Then appending it as an "AND" item to a running total:

                if fe:
                    # If there's an existing fe, append this
                    fe = (fe & fe_class)
                else:
                    # otherwise this is the starting point
                    fe = fe_class

            # Next "OR" term
            # exclusion is also a list of enum values that should match in an OR condition
            if exclusion:
                fe_exclusion = None
                for x in exclusion:
                    fe_x = Attr('exclusion').eq(ArticleExclusion[x].value)
                    if not fe_exclusion:
                        fe_exclusion = fe_x
                    else:
                        fe_exclusion = (fe_exclusion | fe_x)

                # "AND"ed together again:
                if fe:
                    # If there's an existing fe, append this
                    fe = (fe & fe_exclusion)
                else:
                    # otherwise this is the starting point
                    fe = fe_exclusion

            # If the aggregated filter has any Attr's in it, add to request
            if fe:
                request['FilterExpression'] = fe

            response = table.scan(**request)
```

Love to know if there's a better way.